# XSD Enumeration used in a XSLT File

Tags: xslt, xsd

I have this XSD Enumeration :

```
<xs:element name="NeedEnum" type="my:Enum" />

<xs:simpleType name="Enum">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Enumeration 1" id="E_1" />
    <xs:enumeration value="Enumeration 2" id="E_2" />
    <xs:enumeration value="Enumeration 3" id="E_3" />
    <xs:enumeration value="Enumeration 4" id="E_4" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I want to be able to use this simple type/enumeration into a XSLT File to be able to have an **HTML select** populated with those values.

This is my XSLT File so far (just the table part, not all the namespaces) :

```
    <div>
     <select title="Enum" class="">
      <xsl:for-each select="Enum">
       <option>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@value"/>
       </option>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <option>
       <xsl:value-of select="NeedEnum"/>
      </option>
     </select>
    </div>
```

I know that my XSLT file is way off, but I would like to have a select with the value of the options being the enumeration id and the "caption" being the value of the enumeration. I mean I've been reading for a couple of hours and I didn't find anything that could've helped me.

I want to have something like this linked to my NeedEnum :

```
<select title="Enum" >
 <option value="E_1" >Enumeration 1</option>
 <option value="E_2" >Enumeration 2</option>
 <option value="E_3" >Enumeration 3</option>
 <option value="E_4" >Enumeration 4</option>
</select>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you expect the XSLT code to read in that schema as an XML document and to select the `xs:enumeration` elements? Or how do you expect the XSLT code to know or find the values? It is not clear whether your XSLT is using an instance of the schema where you would have an element `NeedEnum` or whether you read in the schema where you would have `xs:element` and `xs:simpleType` elements.

Comment: I would like my XSLT code to detect that my "NeedEnum" as a `xs:enumeration` linked to it, and create my html select populated with my XSD `simpleType`. Yes my XSLT is using an XSD instance that I have generated. So the XSD would never be the same, but my XSLT would create my `<select>` if it's the case. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Does the XML you process with XSLT have an `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute referencing the schema? Which XSLT processor do you use/can you use?

Comment: I don't see this attribute tag, but it has my XML Schema namespace : `<Root xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mynamespace">`. So I guess they're linked ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said anything about your processing environment, but if this is a schema-aware transformation using Saxon-EE, then when `$e` is bound to the (schema-validated) `NeedEnum` element:

```
let $t := saxon:type($e)
```

returns (a representation of) the simple type Enum

```
let $f := $t('facets')[.('class')='enumeration']
```

returns its enumeration facet

```
let $v := $f('values')
```

returns the enumeration values as a sequence of strings.

So you can write:

```
<xsl:for-each select="saxon:type($e)('facets')[.('class')='enumeration']('values')">
   <option value="E_{position()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></option>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The `id` attributes in the schema, unfortunately, are not available.

*(Not tested.)*